# How can i detect mouse left down on datagrid while in the loop?

Tags: c#-4.0, datagrid

During some code is running in loop to update datagird and user click their mouse on data grid suddenly while data is processing.Can i handle their selection while loop is running and then back to the loop;

```
public void procesData()
{
     for(int i = 0;i<=1000000;i++)
    {
       if(Mousedown or something like this)
       {
         //do stuff or handle mousedown event
       }

       //do something


     }

}
```

How to detect their clicking?

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the click event in a event handler of the grid, and then set a flag to true.
The you can check the value of that flag in the loop.

Also, in the event handler you should get the row or cell the user has clicked on.

It might happen that you do not get the event because the UI thread is busy updating the grid with the new values.